# Document Assembly Not Allowed

Tags: livecycle-designer

I created a new fillable form using Adobe LiveCycle Designer. I am unable to "Reader Extend" the form; also, there are no security settings enabled but "Changing the Document" and "Document Assembly" are not allowed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I am not sure what to try at this point. I have done lots of research but have found no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way LiveCycle Designer creates forms.  It creates "XFA" forms where much of the form's behaviour is stored in an "XFA" dictionary within the PDF.

Because of this, non-XFA aware PDF tools that manipulate the PDF without also making the corresponding changes to the XFA portions can cause the form functionality to break.  For this reason, they turn off the "Changing the document" and "Document Assembly" permissions.  In order to protect novice users from performing operations that would likely break their form.

You should be able to Reader Extend a PDF *if* it is saved as a static PDF, not a dynamic PDF.  This imposes some restrictions on the PDF (e.g. it can't dynamically expand/contract to conform to the incoming data).

Most of the functionality you mention *is* available using Adobe's server products (used to be called LiveCycle but is now called Adobe Experience Manager Forms - or AEM Forms for short).  AEM Forms is XFA aware and it can Reader Extend a dynamic PDF.  It can also assemble XFA documents (with some restrictions).